# How to evenly distribute the Series in this way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, distribution

How to solve next issue in Pandas:

So, I have the DataFrame

```
    Man Salary 
    Person 1 - 10000 
    Person 2 - 10000 
    Person 3 - 10000 
    Person 4 - 16000    
    Person 5 - 16000 
    Person 6 - 33000 
    Person 7 - 34000
```

And, wanna get this:

```
Quartile 1: 3 Person, Total Salary — 30000 #1-3 rows
Quartile 2: 2 Person, Total Salary — 32000 #4-5 rows
Quartile 3: 1 Person, Total Salary — 33000 #6 row
Quartile 4: 1 Person, Total Salary — 34000 #7 row
```

Another words, I would like to distribute Salaries Evenly by Total size of Quartile (or Decile for example) with mention, how many rows and which range were used for making this Quartile.
Which is also important: for next each quartile rows should be taken from next unused indexes. That is we cannot take 7 row for Second Quartile, if we haven’t used yet 4-th row

Comment: The usual way would be to use pd.qcut(). Problem with your data set will be that Q3 will be empty try df.describe() as our samples aren't gaussian distributed.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide to percentages by the following line of code:

```
df_percentile = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.salary, np.percentile(df.col0, [0, 25, 75, 100]))).sum()
```